# 1 Parameter, 2 Different Date Entries

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have one table with two different Date Entries: `DateEntered` and `DateShipped`. I am trying to see how many items I received and shipped out in a given date range. The thing that differentiates the two is what type of order they are.

Receiving Orders have only the `DateEntered` field populated, while Shipped Orders have both the `DateEntered` field and `Dateshipped` field populated. The goal is to have one date parameter prompted that will supply a beginning date and an end date for the two dates.

I don't even know if this is possible since the Received Orders' `DateShipped` is always Null in the table. So doing a date range would have to be something like the `Minimum(DateEntered)` to `Maximum(Dateshipped)` and display all the dates that fall within that range. Since `DateShipped` could be null sometimes, I am not sure on how to account for that issue or if this is even possible. How can I specify this behavior?

Comment: Now that I think of it, I may be able to do a subreport, correct? I will only need the totals and the details are suppressed, but that may work. However, the Null with the DateShipped is what may kill me, how do I pass only the one field?

Answer (score 0):

And of course, I figure out how to solve this issue... or at least a way to solve the issue.

I just created a sub report and linked the different dates to each other. DateShipped for the items shipped out to the DateEntered for the Items that came in during the same time frame.